# Karaf switch dependent bundle version without recompile or upload bundle

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I have deployed multiple bundles to my Karaf container. The dependency graf may look that way

```
    A-1.0
     / \
    /   \
B-1.0   C-1.0
```

Both B and C bundles are looking for the newest version of bundle A.
After deployment to production I realized that some interface in bundle A has to changed. I would like that only bundle B knows about that change. Bundle C must remain as it is. Graph would be better then my english.

I would like to acheived something like:

```
A-1.1    A-1.0
  |        |
B-1.1    C-1.0
```

I am wondering is there something like external configuration file which could help or something better maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using Require-Bundle (which, in general you should not do) bundles don't depend on bundles. It's packages that depend on other packages. So for the remainder of my answer I am going to assume that your bundles B and C import some package from A.

The first question then is, what version range do they import?

If both of them import [1.0, 2) (which is pretty normal if they consume services from A) then you won't achieve the effect you are describing.

You can make C import a strict range, like [1.0, 1.1) and then your scenario will work.

I am really wondering why you would want to do what you describe though. If you are correctly applying semantic versioning (as suggested in the OSGi whitepaper) then an update from 1.0 to 1.1 of bundle A means it should be backward compatible. Therefore B and C can use A version 1.1 without any problem. Can you elaborate a bit more about that?

Comment: All bundles are developed simultaneously. The main problem is that i can not touch pacakge C for now(external services are depend on it). For now i added new method to interface and mark old one with deprecated annotation. But in some cases changes can be more complex (A-1.1 is provided logic which is not handled by package C-1.0 but will be by C-1.1). I just wondering if i can use some external configuration to tell the container that package C-1.0 is now going with package A-1.0. In near future i will provide new version of package C-1.1 which will be refactored to use pacakge A-1.1.